# Problems removing registry localStorage

Tags: html

I'm trying to delete a record from localStorage and does not work.

I have a html button with the id that localStorage have to remove:

```
<input type='button' onclick='eliminarDato(this.id)' id=' "+ dato_clave + "' value='Eliminar' />
```

Then, I have the function where the id(clicked_id) correctly received.

```
function eliminarDato(clicked_id)
{
    if(confirm('¿Desea eliminar el favorito seleccionado?'))
            {
                   localStorage.removeItem(clicked_id);
             }
}
```

But the record is not deleted!. What am I doing wrong?. If I replace **localStorage.removeItem(clicked_id);** by **localStorage.removeItem('m1');** is successfully removed. It may be for the quotes? :S

Thanks,
Daniela.

Comment: I can't recall how inline onclick's work off the top of my head, but I'm suspicious of what the arguments are given. What if you try adding `clicked_id` to the confirm dialog? What does it say? The most likely issue here is that clicked_id is not actually 'm1'.

Comment: I just try and if I add in the confirm dialog clicked_id shows m1 (without the quotes). I don't understand why does not delete it :S. In the localstorage the key is m1 and the value m1 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Found it.* But I don't blame you for being confused by this!

```
id=' "+ dato_clave + "'
```

Your problem is the space on that line. Remove the space directly after the single-quote, and the id will be "m1" instead of " m1" (what it was trying to remove). I feel there should be some sort of action you can take to prevent those issues later on, but maybe you'll figure something out for yourself.

Comment: It's true, now works!. Thank you very much!!, You don't know how long ago that I'm trying to work. Really thank you!!!